# How to make slot to except ANY string in Lex?

Tags: amazon-lex

I have a user case where user needs to provide feedback. I have made an intent for taking feedback but I am confused for the slot type.

Can we set slot matching to regex or is any other hacky way available?

Comment: I would suggest filling an empty slot with the inputTranscript. It's the same solution that @sid8491 answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980072/how-to-create-open-ended-slot-in-lex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the built-in slots `AMAZON.MusicCreateWorkType` and `AMAZON.Musician` seem to let you say anything, although maybe everything I said happened to either be a song title or a band name.