# amazon lex regarding slot types used

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am facing problem regarding the slot types used. I want a slot type that must take any kind of input from the user and it must be of free formed data. I had already tried using the `AMAZON.POSTALADDRESS` but it failed many times and it is asking the question again and again.
I had also tried using the `AMAZON.STREETADDRESS` it also failed and the bot is repeating the question again and again and quitting out of the app.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create open-ended slot in lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980072/how-to-create-open-ended-slot-in-lex)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

- Make a slot
- Do not tick required option
- In the DialogCodeHook, make the slot value `NULL`
- Now, check if the slot is `NULL` then provide `ElicitSlot`
- In `ElicitSlot`, take the `inputTranscript` and assign it to the slot
  value

`slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
slots['your_slot'] = intent_request['inputTranscript']`

Hope it helps.

Comment: if we donot tick the required option then how then prompt is not working.

Comment: you can manage it in Lambda function. read about `ElicitSlot` in the examples given.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AMAZON.MoviesSeries` as a slot type.

I hope it will help.