# LEX slot type for file name. AMAZON.LITERAL replacement

Tags: aws-lex

I have to create an intent with sample utterances

- "open file 'fileName'"
- "show 'fileName'"
- ...

Basically, I have to have a slot which accepts file name. User can type

- "open my file *report.pdf*"
- "open file *activity1.doc*"
- "open file *last year report*"

It would work perfectly If I could use AMAZON.LITERAL type, but it is deprecated.

What slot type I can use? Or how to extract file name (or basically any text with no type)

So far I have tested with below slot types and all not perfect:

- Created custom slot type (but I can't add all possible file names, because of that it doesn't work all the time)
- AMAZON.Organization
- AMAZON.Actor

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I'm facing the same situation. THanks!